# FluentValidation and .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, nuget-package, fluentvalidation, fluent

I've just installed FluentValidation 11.5.1 for my project which uses .NET 4.5 but I can't install FluentValidation.AspNetCore due to incompatibility with my .NET version. After doing some research I am finding conflicting information on which version of FluentValidation works with 4.5 - some articles mentioned 3.0.0 others 5.0.0, and the documentation on the FluentValidation website only go to the 8.0.0 upgrade. Can I use FluentValidation 11.5.1 without FluentValidation.AspNetCore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Fluent Validation docs, [v11 only supports .NET Core 3.1+ and .NET Standard 2.0](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/), which is [not compatible with .NET Framework 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0).

Checking nuget and GitHub, we can see the [.NET Framework 4.5 support was dropped in version 9](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/releases/tag/9.0-preview1), so the latest you can use is [version 8.6.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation/8.6.3).